# selenium can't find all needed elements in page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, element, microsoft-edge

I use python and Edge browser
I need to get 60 "[data-sqe='name']" but console only output 30 items.
It seems to the page loaded by webdriver can not load fully even i added sleep for 15s for loading time.
I tried some way but the page even does not show the scroller (1st pic).
Please help me to find all items i need.
`Name= [my_elem.text for my_elem in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.row.shopee-search-item-result__items > div > a div[data-sqe='name'] +div")]`
in site:
https://shopee.vn/search?keyword=iphone&page=0&sortBy=sales

[image: the page loaded by webdrive]

Answer (score 0):

```
    As per my assumption, you can write the Refresh() Method post landing on the page or you can write the for loop and if condition and this loop will polling every 5 seconds.
    
    1- Method
    driver.navigate().Refresh();
    
    2- Method
    int RetryforRefresh=10;
    for(int i=1;i<=RetryforRefresh.size();i++)
    {
    //here gave the XPath of the element which appears after some time.
    if(driver.findelement(By.xpath(""))).isDisplayed()==true)
    {
    //print page loaded successfully
    Break;
    }
    else
    {
    driver.navigate().Refresh();
    }
    }
3- For finding all the elements from the page, probably you can use the cssSelector for that.

Webelement allElement=driver.findelement(By.CssSelector("*"));

String allElemt=allElement.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like you can't load all the elements due to lazy loading. so you can try scrolling down the page using the execute_script method of webdriver. as an example:

```
for i in range(5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)

name_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.row.shopee-search-item-result__items > div > a div[data-sqe='name'] +div")
```

Comment: i tried it before but the page was controlled by driver even does not have the scroll  
And i applied your code and only 15 items searched

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete solution if you want to scrape all the data from a single page.

```
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = ChromeOptions()
# maximized and disable forbar
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://shopee.vn/search?keyword=iphone&page=0&sortBy=sales")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="row shopee-search-item-result__items"]')))

for i in range(5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1000);")
    sleep(2)

data = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

data = []
results = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"data-sqe": "item"})
for result in results:
    temp = {
        "link": f"https://shopee.vn{result.findNext('a').get('href')}",
        "image": result.findNext('img').get('src'),
        "title": result.findNext("div", attrs={"data-sqe": "name"}).findChild('div').text,
        "price": result.findNext("div", attrs={"class": "hpDKMN"}).text
    }
    data.append(temp)

print(data)
```

the variable data will contain the list of informations of all 60 data points

```
print(data)

[
  {
    'link': 'https://shopee.vn/Kính-cường-lực-iphone-21D-full-màn-6-6plus-6s-6splus-7-7plus-8-8plus-x-xs-11-12-13-pro-max-promax-Shin-Case-Ốp-lưng-i.89827191.3302939384?sp_atk=6738b6f5-860f-4c60-b7a3-4a2972305732&xptdk=6738b6f5-860f-4c60-b7a3-4a2972305732',
    'image': 'https://cf.shopee.vn/file/e87cf916088d064696a93826ae46ce55_tn',
    'title': 'Kính cường lực iphone 21D full màn 6/6plus/6s/6splus/7/7plus/8/8plus/x/xs/11/12/13/pro/max/promax/Shin Case/Ốp lưng',
    'price': '₫1.380 - ₫6.900'
  },
  {
    'link': 'https://shopee.vn/Kính-cường-lực-iphone-KingKong-6-6plus-6s-6splus-7-7plus-8-8plus-x-xs-11-12-13-pro-max-promax-Shin-Case-Ốp-lưng-i.89827191.2608753400?sp_atk=0407e7a1-4692-4f1b-9bbb-a197cc1f722c&xptdk=0407e7a1-4692-4f1b-9bbb-a197cc1f722c',
    'image': 'https://cf.shopee.vn/file/78a15f18b22564431a2f4be25b015f06_tn',
    'title': 'Kính cường lực iphone KingKong 6/6plus/6s/6splus/7/7plus/8/8plus/x/xs/11/12/13/pro/max/promax/Shin Case/Ốp lưng',
    'price': '₫3.980 - ₫19.900'
  },
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  {
    'link': 'https://shopee.vn/Ốp-Điện-Thoại-Mềm-Trong-Suốt-3-Trong-1-Cho-Iphone-14-13-12-11-Pro-Promax-6-6S-SE-7-8-Plus-X-XR-XSMax-i.738752794.17841035109?sp_atk=a4d7604c-f8e5-4152-bd0f-6902cb983e7e&xptdk=a4d7604c-f8e5-4152-bd0f-6902cb983e7e',
    'image': 'https://cf.shopee.vn/file/2764bf1b00e333ba128e402620bba34e_tn',
    'title': 'Ốp Điện Thoại Mềm Trong Suốt 3 Trong 1 Cho Iphone 14 13 12 11 Pro Promax 6 6S SE 7 8 Plus X XR XSMax',
    'price': '₫9.900 - ₫14.000'
  },
  {
    'link': 'https://shopee.vn/Ốp-điện-thoại-TPU-thích-hợp-cho-6-6plus-6s-6splus-7-7plus-8-8plus-x-xs-xr-xsmax-11-12-13-14-pro-max-plus-promax-001-i.714299051.14462608681?sp_atk=bf4ae52a-495c-47c1-999e-5843721560d7&xptdk=bf4ae52a-495c-47c1-999e-5843721560d7',
    'image': 'https://cf.shopee.vn/file/414fb83535aee0be087083f42849b5e0_tn',
    'title': 'Ốp điện thoại TPU thích hợp cho 6 / 6plus / 6s / 6splus / 7 / 7plus / 8 / 8plus / x / xs / xr / xsmax / 11 / 12 / 13 /14 pro / max / plus / promax-001',
    'price': '₫4.500'
  }
]
```

Comment: i tried many times to use chrome driver instead of Edge driver but no work. So i can not tried your code. Can you change it to Edge browser?

Comment: I've added another answer with the Edge browser as you asked, it works the same as the Chrome Browser and gives the same list of all 60 data points on the given page.

Answer (score 0):

Here, for Edge Browser. It works the same like Chrome Browser

```
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys, EdgeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

options = EdgeOptions()
# maximized and disable forbar
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
driver.get("https://shopee.vn/search?keyword=iphone&page=0&sortBy=sales")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[class="row shopee-search-item-result__items"]')))

for i in range(5):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 1000);")
    sleep(2)

data = driver.page_source
driver.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

data = []
results = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"data-sqe": "item"})
for result in results:
    temp = {
        "link": f"https://shopee.vn{result.findNext('a').get('href')}",
        "image": result.findNext('img').get('src'),
        "title": result.findNext("div", attrs={"data-sqe": "name"}).findChild('div').text,
        "price": result.findNext("div", attrs={"class": "hpDKMN"}).text
    }
    data.append(temp)

print(data)
```

And gives the same output as we get with Chrome browser.

```
print(data)

[
  {
    'link': 'https://shopee.vn/Kính-cường-lực-iphone-21D-full-màn-6-6plus-6s-6splus-7-7plus-8-8plus-x-xs-11-12-13-pro-max-promax-Shin-Case-Ốp-lưng-i.89827191.3302939384?sp_atk=6738b6f5-860f-4c60-b7a3-4a2972305732&xptdk=6738b6f5-860f-4c60-b7a3-4a2972305732',
    'image': 'https://cf.shopee.vn/file/e87cf916088d064696a93826ae46ce55_tn',
    'title': 'Kính cường lực iphone 21D full màn 6/6plus/6s/6splus/7/7plus/8/8plus/x/xs/11/12/13/pro/max/promax/Shin Case/Ốp lưng',
    'price': '₫1.380 - ₫6.900'
  },
  {
    'link': 'https://shopee.vn/Kính-cường-lực-iphone-KingKong-6-6plus-6s-6splus-7-7plus-8-8plus-x-xs-11-12-13-pro-max-promax-Shin-Case-Ốp-lưng-i.89827191.2608753400?sp_atk=0407e7a1-4692-4f1b-9bbb-a197cc1f722c&xptdk=0407e7a1-4692-4f1b-9bbb-a197cc1f722c',
    'image': 'https://cf.shopee.vn/file/78a15f18b22564431a2f4be25b015f06_tn',
    'title': 'Kính cường lực iphone KingKong 6/6plus/6s/6splus/7/7plus/8/8plus/x/xs/11/12/13/pro/max/promax/Shin Case/Ốp lưng',
    'price': '₫3.980 - ₫19.900'
  },
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  {
    'link': 'https://shopee.vn/Ốp-Điện-Thoại-Mềm-Trong-Suốt-3-Trong-1-Cho-Iphone-14-13-12-11-Pro-Promax-6-6S-SE-7-8-Plus-X-XR-XSMax-i.738752794.17841035109?sp_atk=a4d7604c-f8e5-4152-bd0f-6902cb983e7e&xptdk=a4d7604c-f8e5-4152-bd0f-6902cb983e7e',
    'image': 'https://cf.shopee.vn/file/2764bf1b00e333ba128e402620bba34e_tn',
    'title': 'Ốp Điện Thoại Mềm Trong Suốt 3 Trong 1 Cho Iphone 14 13 12 11 Pro Promax 6 6S SE 7 8 Plus X XR XSMax',
    'price': '₫9.900 - ₫14.000'
  },
  {
    'link': 'https://shopee.vn/Ốp-điện-thoại-TPU-thích-hợp-cho-6-6plus-6s-6splus-7-7plus-8-8plus-x-xs-xr-xsmax-11-12-13-14-pro-max-plus-promax-001-i.714299051.14462608681?sp_atk=bf4ae52a-495c-47c1-999e-5843721560d7&xptdk=bf4ae52a-495c-47c1-999e-5843721560d7',
    'image': 'https://cf.shopee.vn/file/414fb83535aee0be087083f42849b5e0_tn',
    'title': 'Ốp điện thoại TPU thích hợp cho 6 / 6plus / 6s / 6splus / 7 / 7plus / 8 / 8plus / x / xs / xr / xsmax / 11 / 12 / 13 /14 pro / max / plus / promax-001',
    'price': '₫4.500'
  }
]
```

Comment: Make sure that you download and use the same version of Edge driver as your Edge browser.